# Does the Horned Rat appear in WarHammer 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Horned Rat is the God of all Skavens in WarHammer Battle, and is a minor Chaos God compared to the 4 main Chaos God.

WarHammer Battle and WarHammer 40k are two separate universes, but they have a very similar mythology, with many gods in common. Though there is no "skavens in space", has the Horned Rat ever been mentioned as a minor Chaos God in 40k (in a Codex, or a novel, or any official material) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Nope

As you point out in your question, there are no skaven in space.

A chaos god gets all of it's power from it's worshipers, and there are no skaven to worship it so the [Horned Rat](http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Horned_Rat) just couldn't exist in 40k. **And to my knowledge, there has been absolutely no mention of it in any of the army books or fluff.**

I've always assumed that the numberless tyranids were the 40k equivalent of skaven, since the burrowing rat men probably wouldn't translate to space very well.

In the fantasy universe at least, it's arguable that the Horned Rat is the most powerful of all the Chaos gods as it undoubtedly has the most followers, they're just to busy backstabbing each other to ever do anything. ([Until the End Times anyway](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Morrslieb)).

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

- There are more than just 4 "Gods" in the 40k universe
- There is a reference to a minor God called Malice.

First, there are more than just four Chaos Gods. There are four Major Chaos Gods, but there are a number of Minor Gods that exist in the warp as well. A great many consider Daemons to be Gods, but Daemons are created from the Chaos Gods powers to do their bidding. Really the question comes down to what do you accept as canon, since both Games Workshop and the Warhammer fanbase battle both with each other and themselves as to what is and is not canon.

Now we know the two universes are linked through the warp; but I do not think we know for sure whether Fantasy comes before 40k or not. It might actually follow or be concurrent... The chaos gods are always susceptible to shifts, especially in the "minor arenas" but I have never heard of the Horned Rat in 40k. But the fact that some Gods are prominent in both universes is key that it is possible to be in both.

I found a post that referenced him in 40k as the Horned Prince, but even if that were true the site labeled him as a Daemon prince. To my knowledge no Daemon Prince has ever found a way to become a Chaos God, minor or otherwise... Though it is possible for a Chaos God to use all of its power as a God to create a Daemon and thus transform from a God to a Daemon.

It does seem however that there is mention of a Minor God named Malice, The Lost God. He is named in a short story called Labyrinth by Richard Ford. I mention this because in my research I found references to The Great Horned Rat as Malal or Malice and malice, blight, etc. are part of his repertoire. There is also a confirmed Space Marine Chapter that was excommunicated when they turned to Chaos and began to follow this Minor Chaos God.

Comment: 1. Games Workshop and W40k are the same thing. Games Workshop made both Warhammer and the W40k universe. 2. There are NO other gods than the 4. Greater or lower daemons live and die at the whims of the 4 Gods. 3. the Warhammer and W40k worlds are not connected and have never been. this has been stated by Games Workshop so many times that my eyes will bleed out if I cite all the references.

Comment: 1. GW and 40k are not the same thing. GW created WHfantasy and WH40,000. Fantasy and 40k are connected through the warp. 2. I do not buy into the whole "despite what exists it is not canon" philosophy. The Sons of Malice ARE CANON, because GW officially sanctioned works with information referring to them. That alone proves you wrong. That is why we source things. 3. GW like other things has created a canon conflict on this in their later talks but even if they are not connected, there is still so much that translates from one to the other that it still holds no bearing on the initial question.

Comment: The great thing I love about 40k is the fact that there is so much conflicting information, because it opens the universe even more. Anything is possible. The question was is there a mention of a Minor God that could be the Horned Rat. I did not do a boat load of research because after finding the confirmed Sons of Malice I really needed no other proof that Minor Gods exist. The possible connections between the Horned Rat and Malice are noteworthy and, though I did not officially say the big rat is a part of 40k, I have provided sufficient evidence that it is possible.

Comment: But Malal is no more canon? http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Malal and appear to be the god of rebellion, unrelated to the skaven.

Comment: Malal is no the horned god, Malal was a god games workshop created who was a chaos god that attempted to stop the other chaos gods.

Comment: @RichardC: IIRC, Malal is not even a GW creation. It was created by a third company that made the Warhammer RPG. I don't know whether GW ever stated it was canon or not.

Comment: I never commented on that answer! Sorry. Thanks for the answer but it does not really answer the question. The existence of more than 4 Chaos Gods (which I believe GW never denied) does not imply the presence of the Horned Rat in 40k.  I dont really buy the theory Malal/Malice=Horned Rat. This answer would be better on another question of mine about the existence of other gods.

Answer (score 5):

The 1989 compendium mentions that Ratlings sniper rifles have a skaven toxin available. The Skaven were also planned to be included in Warhammer 40k at some point, as mentionned by Jes Goodwin in "The Gothic and the Eldritch", which includes a few sketches of 40k skaven (They were mostly WWI-inspired apparently, with a lot of chemical warfare). This never went anywhere though, and there are no mentions of the Horned Rat anywhere in Warhammer 40k.

Comment: It reminded the Codex Imperialis of the 2nd edition that was giving rules for Beastmen and bows :)

Answer (score 0):

**NO**
There are 4 "Gods" in the W40k universe.

[Khorne](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Khorne)

[Slaneesh](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Slaanesh)

[Tzeentch](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Tzeentch)

[Nurgle](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nurgle)

There might me a minor daemon of Nurgle that could posses the same/similar characteristics as the "Horned god". Pestilence is the domain of Nurgle.

Comment: Could you give an official reference to justify there are only 4 Chaos gods? I find the Lexicanum quite imprecise on that point. For example, the Khorne entry describes him as "one of the 4 Chaos god" (not major or main god, just god) but the introduction of Chaos god does not give any number, and speaks about "the least of minor gods"

Comment: And the Slaanesh entry calls him "the last of major Chaos gods".

Comment: Best source would prob be the Chaos space marines codex (dont have the newest revision at hand). all this talk about major and minor gods is moot. there are 4 chaos gods period. Everything else is just greater deamons of one of the 4. all of the other entities exist as playthings for the chaos gods. There might be gods of the other races tho. Necrons have some beeings that are powerfull enough to be considered gods. Orcs have Gork and Mork etc. how they classify on the "God" scale I have no idea.

Comment: Without source, "there are 4 chaos gods period" is only your opinion. I created a question about that.