# Why aren't Gork and Mork chaos gods?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Lists of chaos gods generally focus on the Khorne, Slaanesh, Nurgle, and Tzeentch, with the Emperor sometimes being considered among their number (if you are being heretical). Malal is sometimes considered another, when people remember that he existed.

But what about Gork and Mork? Why aren't they included in lists of chaos gods? They've certainly got a lot of worshippers.

Comment: Maybe Mork's rainbow suspenders set him apart from the rest of the gang? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because they are something else.

They can't offer you a deal "power for your soul" because they are not interested in giving you power ("Real Ork takez power hm'self!") and are not interested in your soul ("Woz dad?"). Occasionally they can give a blessing to a powerful warboss or a weirdboy, but most of the time they are focused on trying to kill each other (one is cunning but brutal, the other brutal but cunning <sup>1</sup>).

They don't look for new worshippers - Orks believe in them naturally from birth and although there are un-orky traitors that worship Chaos gods... or [even the Emperor](http://www.coolminiornot.com/pics/pics11/img464bb01ab4abf.jpg) ("He is da great git in Golden prizun!"), the wast majority believes in them unconditionally. Gork and Mork also don't have a huge plans to conquer the universe - they are happy to fight each other and occasionally help few greenskins in their Waaagh! (which can be best been described as "1/2 holy crusade, 1/2  pub crawl").

It is also speculated that they are not, like the Chaos gods, beings born in the Warp - instead they have been created by the weird psy-concious that all Orks have, which makes red cars go faster and their technology to work in the first place - simply Orks decided that there must be someone "dad is much bettur at cunning and bashing" and here they became (this is also the main reason you wouldn't call Emperor a Chaos god, you heretic!)

### tl;dr

- They don't have demons
- They don't look for/corrupt new worshippers
- They don't come from the Warp

Also, apparently they could easily take the Chaos gods down... if they would stop fighting each others

<sup>1 Mork hits you when you aren't looking and Gork hits you even harder when you are. Or the other way around.</sup>

Comment: I'm sure somewhere in the old fluff there was a story about either Gork or Mork throwing Khorne across the Warp

Comment: @TommyBs If enough Orks believe it, it comes true. There is a joke somewhere was Khorne doesn't leave his throne because hes paraplegic. Gork and Mork would be pretty good reasons why.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere someone summarising that Gork and Mork are the "Warp manifestation of the collective of orks believing in their existence"; a bit like the shadow in the warp is the manifestation of billions of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

[Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gork_and_Mork) calls Gork & Mork warp manifestations of Orks' emotions and traits, and being that Orks are numerous and their psi abilities are unique & identifiable in the Galaxy, their warp reflection(s) are also unique. Ork behavior is not chaotic--it's violent, but otherwise hierarchical and predictable. Therefore I think the business of Orks lies outside of the purview of the four Chaos gods.